# Wordpress: Add any post without author to admin user

Tags: wordpress

I have 200 post in my site without any author.

How can i add this post to admin user in wordpress wp-admin or by sql

Answer (score 1):

Use the following SQL on your database:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author = 1 WHERE post_author = NULL
```

Where `wp_posts` is the name of your posts table, and `1` is the ID of your admin user. Also if the `post_author` is something other than `NULL` update the `WHERE` clause appropriately.

Comment: Change the ,,1'' used here to the admin ID you want change owners...  (Not all blogs have that user!)